# Can't connect to internet with dynamic IP

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, windows-7, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I have a small business network with the DNS server being run on Windows Server 2003. Most of the computers in the company have a dynamic IP address assigned through the aforementioned server. One of the Windows 7 computers has difficulty connecting to the internet unless we assign a static IP. It has no trouble connecting to the intranet though. I went through the DNS settings on the server and there are no conflicting IP addresses. Obviously this is trivial to solve by just assigning a static IP, but I would like to know why the dynamic IP is not working and how I could solve it.

Any ideas would be appreciated and I will be more than happy to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this machine on a domain?

Some squirrely issues can be caused by having a network set as something other than a "Home" network in Windows 7. Also, `netsh winsock reset` may help<strike>, so may Dial-A-Fix</strike> (Dial-A-Fix does not work with Windows 7, per [here](http://wiki.lunarsoft.net/wiki/Dial-a-fix)). Also, ensure the machine is getting the proper DNS suffix and the gateway is an IP (not a hostname).

Try a `traceroute` and see if it gets beyond the gateway, and check DNS servers per the other posts.

Comment: Yes, it is on a domain. I will verify if it is set to a Home network or not and will run the commands you listed and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Have you asigned a Default Gateway and DNS servers in the DHCP steup? This will assure teh clinet gets an IP address, a Gateway and DNS servers.  Sometiimes I have found you may need to add the internal DNS server as teh first DNS server and then your ISPs DNS as second, third, etc.

Comment: The client is getting an IP address. They are being assigned 192.168.2.71 which is within the DHCP scope. And they are capable of getting on the intranet, but for some reason they have trouble getting outside of the intranet to the internet

Comment: Look at the DHCP server under Scope Options and look for DNS server and Router (which assigns the gateway) If they cannot reach internet, the DNS or Gateway is the issue. Simply PING www.cisco.com or a know site and see if you get a reply that resolves the IP. If not, DNS has issues. –

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command from command prompt on the machine that is having issues connecting to the internet:

IPCONFIG /ALL

Confirm the machine has an IP address, Default Gateway and DNS assigned. Check these against another machine that is currently working and running DHCP.

Comment: I will do this at lunch time and post the answers

Answer (score 0):

DNS doesn't assign ip addresses. DHCP assigns ip addresses. Have you looked at your DHCP scope to make sure there are sufficient ip addresses for all of your hosts?

Comment: Okay, I opened up the DNS tool in Administrative tools in order to view the used ip addresses and their corresponding names. You are saying I should look at the DHCP tool? I just did that based on your answer and this particular computer is assigned 192.168.2.71 and everything else looks fine...The scope allows for everything from .50 to .199

Answer (score 0):

Disable IPv6 on the NIC for the client.  I've heard of issues created by having this enabled if you're not running IPv6 internally.